# 24 Children, 6 types of candy, 4 of each candy. How many ways are there to give all the children one candy?

Tags: permutations

Let's say you have 24 children, and 6 different flavours of candy, which 4 of each flavour. A child cannot get more than one candy. How many ways are there to distribute these 6 flavours of candy?

Edit: The solution

For the first flavor, 4 of the 24 students are selected. Then for the second flavor, 4 students are selected from the 20 students who remain, and so on. Thus, the number of different ways to distribute the 6 flavors of
candy to 24 children is:

(24 choose 4) * (20 choose 4) * (16 choose 4) * ... * (4 choose 4) = 24! / (4!)^6

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a place where people solve homework problems for free, it's a place where you can come for help if you're stuck on something or have a question about a problem.

Comment: I have found the solution offline, and added it to the question for future reference. I was having trouble understanding how to approach the question, and thus only calculated basic combinations (such as 24 choose 4, or 24 choose 6, multiplied by 6 or 4, respectively). I didn't believe these were significant enough to add to the initial question.